# Missed declaration?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using WordPress on-line and I'm a not experienced programmer. Trying to embed a js-script on one side which should produce the following line:

> Idag är det Onsdag, den 02 November 2016 och Tobias  har namnsdag.

My problem is that the name **Tobias**, produced by the script `NamedayHandler.js` is not displayed. The problem is that that script is located in another directory.
The script  I try to embed  is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="Adobe PageMill 2.0 Win">
  <BASE TARGET="_top">
  <TITLE></TITLE>
  <META NAME="description" CONTENT="Eivor och Bengt Ohlsson's hemsida">
  <META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="bengt,eivor,ohlsson,resor,turism,kultur,sol,bad,resa,radar">
<script type="text/javascript" src="eivorobengt.se/NamedayHandler.js"></script>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
        new NamedayHandler({elm: 'namnsdag'});
}
</script>

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->
<!--  Author: www.cgiscript.net  -->

<!-- Begin

// Get today's current date.
var now = new Date();

// Array list of days.
var days = new Array('Söndag','Måndag','Tisdag','Onsdag','Torsdag','Fredag','Lördag');

// Array list of months.
var months = new Array('Januari','Februari','Mars','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','Augusti','September','Oktober','November','December');

// Calculate the number of the current day in the week.
var date = ((now.getDate()<10) ? "0" : "")+ now.getDate();

// Calculate four digit year.
function fourdigits(number) {
    return (number < 1000) ? number + 1900 : number;
                                }

// Join it all together

today =  "Idag är det " +
         days[now.getDay()] + ", " +"den " +
         date + " " +
         months[now.getMonth()] + " " +
         (fourdigits(now.getYear())) + " och" ;

// Print out the data.

document.write (today);

//  End -->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript src="NamedayHandler.js"></script>
 <span id="namnsdag"></span> har namnsdag.</FONT>    </p>   
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This gives the folloving error:

> "ReferenceError: eivorobengt is not defined".

What shall I do?

Comment: `eivorobengt.se` check in this foldername are there.And why applied with `.` extention of the folder

Comment: Is the script trying to access `<span id="namnsdag">` ? Because that's not yet defined when it's loaded. We can't really tell though, mostly because you say the script is in another directory (is there an error message in the console? Do you mean the script isn't loading?) and you don't tell us what's in the script!